# Display pdf blob file from database

Tags: php, html, pdf, blob

I have stored pdf file into database i.e blob type.
Now I wanna display pdf like

```
$sqll="select * from pdff";
$query=mysql_query($sqll) or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$content=$result['pdf'];
<object data="<?php echo $content;?>" type="application/pdf" style="height:200px;width:60%"></object>
```

but in browser it shows..

```
> endobj 6 0 obj << /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ] /ColorSpace << /Cs1 7 0 R /Cs2 10 0 R >> /ExtGState << /Gs2 34 0 R /Gs1 35 0 R >> /Font << /F1.0 31 0 R >> /XObject << /Im4 21 0 R /Im1 8 0 R /Im3 16 0 R /Im2 11 0 R /Im5 26 0 R /Im6 32 0 R /Fm3 23 0 R /Fm1 13 0 R /Fm2 18 0 R /Fm4 28 0 R >> /Properties << /Pl2 36 0 R /Pl1 37 0 R >> >> endobj 23 0 obj << /Length 24 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode /Type /XObject /Subtype /Form /FormType 1 /BBox [649 536 669 556] /Resources 25 0 R /Group << /S /Transparency /CS 10 0 R /I true /K false >> >> stream xMŽAƒ0ï}Å¾ÀÄ‰mÈ¹/àÄU+Íÿ¥:(\|˜]ïî etc
```

and I tried

```
 <object data="<?php echo base64_decode($content);?>" type="application/pdf" style="height:200px;width:60%"></object>
```

but no use...please help meeee

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I have been working on `yii` as developer,before on `yii`,I just tried on php,,ok. And I need help...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your data still in `Blob`, you need to encode your data using `base64_encode()`.
Please try it

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(content) ?>" type="application/pdf" style="height:200px;width:60%"></object>
```

Comment: resolved by using an iframe tag ..thank you @Dolly Aswin

Answer (score 3):

I hope the following will do exactly what you want:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=name.pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile("data:application/pdf;base64,$content");
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old but I recently had a similar issue to solve and wrote this quick guide to cover it.
https://medium.com/@alexmoran_19787/display-pdf-from-blob-file-11996146dbc0

Basically Depending on if you addslashes or not when inputing the pdf into the database you can view it by the following
I had this in my controller and passed the info to a php page. Setting the headers and if you addslashes make sure to stripslashes otherwise you will just end up with the raw data or blank screen.

```
    $content = stripslashes($text["file"]);
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=document.pdf');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    
    $this->load->view("administrator/load_pdf", [
        "title"=>"Display PDF",
        "pdf"=>$content,
    ]);
```

This is from the php page.

```
  <object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($content);?>" type="application/pdf" height="100%" width="100%"></object>
```

Comment: This just saved me.  stripslashes was my issue.

Comment: glad its still helping.