# Pulling pdf BLOB from database using php and displaying it in a html page not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdf, mime-types

I am trying to retrieve a blob pdf then display it on the page.
I am using the following code however only the base 64 string is being displayed instead of the pdf which is my desired output.

The following is the code that I am using.

```
<?php
    //header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    require 'connect.php';
    $db=mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password,$mysql_dbName);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE id = 1688";
    $sth = $db->query($sql);
    $result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
    $pdf = base64_encode($result['file']);
    echo $pdf;
?>
<object data="<?php echo $pdf ?>" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

I have tried using

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(content) ?>" type="application/pdf" style="height:200px;width:60%"></object>
```

And also putting it in an iframe like this

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($result['file']) ?>" type="application/pdf">
    <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($result['file']) ?>"></iframe>
</object>
```

But the pdf file fails to load.

**-----------EDIT 5/8/17--------**

I am now adding an iframe dynamically using the code below yet I get an error saying that

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/pdf:

here is my newly added javascript

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

var src = $('#hiddenBase64').val();//this stores the base64 string

$(iframe).width("100%");

$(iframe).height("100%");

iframe.src = "data:application/pdf;base64," + src;

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This has been answered already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948761/display-pdf-blob-file-from-database

Comment: I have looked at this answer however when I try this method the pdf file fails to load.

Comment: Read the comments, the user needed to put it in an iframe.

Comment: When I put it in an Iframe the pdf still fails to load. I am not too familiar with using iframes I am creating the iframe like this.


<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($result['file']) ?>" type="application/pdf">
    <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($result['file']) ?>"></iframe>
</object>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't really getting anywhere with this and have read [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database) that it is bad practice to store files in the database. (I wasn't able to figure out why the pdf failed to load)

What I am doing now is storing the file in a subfolder on my server. Then I am storing a link to the file in the database and to display the file I just run a select query that pulls the link and then I have the link.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the echo $pdf. This will output the base64_encoded pdf before the  as well.