# Showing (pdf) content of LONGBLOB in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show the PDF file that is stored in my LONGBLOB. When I execute the code I only get the name of the file. I want to show the PDF file in a viewer.

Does someone know how I can fix this?

Here is my script:

```
          <?php
            $tpurchase_id = $_GET['tpurchase_id'];
            $conn = new mysqli("localhost","user","","db");
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM temp_purchase WHERE tpurchase_id= '$tpurchase_id'";

            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                header("Content-type:application/pdf");

                $a=$row['content'];
                echo '<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,';
                echo base64_decode($a); 
                echo '" type="application/pdf" style="height:200px;width:60%"></object>';
              }
            }
            $conn->close();

          ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display pdf blob file from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948761/display-pdf-blob-file-from-database)

Comment: `echo $a=$row['content'];` should not be an echo there

Comment: I changed it. When I execute the script I see in my browser that `echo base64_decode($a); ` is returning question marks instead of the decoded variable

Comment: @LuisCardozaBird `base64_encode($a); ` returns `Error: Failed to load PDF document.`

Comment: Step 1: Stop lying to the browser. `header("Content-type:application/pdf");` followed by _HTML code_ (instead of actual, binary PDF data) makes no sense.

Comment: I have deleted `header("Content-type:application/pdf");`. I am not lying anymore to the browser :)

Comment: What step encodes into base64?

Comment: @RickJames what do you mean?

Comment: @John - Show us the code that `INSERTed` the `content`.

Comment: Do you want to show multiple PDF files on a single page?

Comment: @John you should flow problem with you script is you are not concatenating the string properly. You should use fyrye ' s solution it looks good to me.

Comment: @John if you don't mind can you use http://www.tcpdf.org for making PDF, TCPDF has many options, you should try once.

Answer (score 2):

I think this sould work without problem , giving more headers informations

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="thing.pdf"');
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($row['content']));

print $row['content'];
```

Comment: When I execute the script I only get the name of the file (test.pdf). I cannot see the content in my browser

Answer (score 2):

Some order of operations improvements and optimizations.
Assuming the database is correctly storing the entire contents of the `LOB` data.

Output buffering using `ob_start`, `ob_clean`, and `ob_end_flush` will provide more control over the desired response content from your script. This will help to alleviate erroneous spaces or emitted warnings from being included in the binary output.
Additionally this allows for you to control which `header` data to send in the response.

There's no need to use `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` since the response from the database should contain the entirety of the single `LONGBLOB` data row.

Using [`mysqli_stmt::bind_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) and [`mysqli_stmt::fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) will reduce some overhead caused by fetching into an associative array, since its only needed to retrieve the content.  `mysqli_stmt::fetch` will return `NULL` if there are no results/data or `false` on error.

I also suggest using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), to prevent SQL injections and  [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to ensure the user supplied input is of the expected data type and is valid.

Using `content-disposition: inline` will ask the browser to attempt to load it, if the browser can understand the `content-type`, otherwise it will download it.

Lastly you do not need to end your code with  `?>`, which can cause unintended behavior, instead just use `exit;`. It's best to exclude the closing tag in your PHP script files unless you are transitioning from PHP to plain text or markup in the same file.

I tested the below against my MySQL database table that also uses `LONGBLOB` to store PDF files and is functioning as desired.

```
<?php /*line 1*/
ob_start(); //start output buffering immediately
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','user','','db');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit;
}
$tpurchase_id = filter_var($_GET['tpurchase_id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT tp.content 
FROM temp_purchase AS tp 
WHERE tp.tpurchase_id = ? 
AND tp.content > ""'); //ensure content is not empty
if ($stmt && false !== $tpurchase_id) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $tpurchase_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($content);
    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
        //a record was found, change to a PDF file
        ob_clean(); //clear the buffer
        header('content-type: application/pdf');
        header('content-disposition: inline; filename="Test.pdf"');
        echo $content;
        ob_end_flush(); //output only the buffered content to the client
    }
    $stmt->close();
    unset($content, $stmt);
}
$conn->close(); //always close the connection
while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
   ob_end_clean(); //remove everything else from the buffer
}
exit;
```

This will result in only the headers and content response being sent to the client, otherwise if a result from the database is not found, a blank plain/text response is sent.

The above script can then be used as the source for your inline object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<object data="/path/to/above_script.php?tpurchase_id=123" type="application/pdf" style="height:200px;width:60%"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

Aside from the above, there other points that can cause issues, which we are currently not aware of.

- Headers added or modified by the webserver  (apache, nginx, IIS, etc).
- Upload form or PHP processing script modifying or not sending complete `LOB` data to the database.
- Database truncating or altering the `LOB` data.

---

To use the above PHP script for displaying inline `object`(s). There's no need for output buffering. However you would need to swap out `base64_decode` in favor of using `base64_encode`. Decode takes a base64 encoded string and converts it to the original format. Where you actually want to take the binary data from the database and convert it to a base64 encoded string for the browser to later decode. If the file content has already been `base64_encode`'d by the upload processing script, neither `base64_encode` or `base64_decode` is needed.

Tested the below and is functioning as desired.

```
<?php /*line 1*/
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','user','','db');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit;
}
$tpurchase_id = filter_var($_GET['tpurchase_id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT tp.content 
FROM temp_purchase AS tp 
WHERE tp.tpurchase_id = ? 
AND tp.content > ""'); //ensure content is not empty
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if ($stmt && false !== $tpurchase_id) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $tpurchase_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($content);
    if ($stmt->fetch()) { ?>
        <object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($content); ?>" type="application/pdf" style="height:200px;width:60%"></object>
    <?php }
    $stmt->close();
    unset($content, $stmt);
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

For the purposes of retrieving multiple documents, you can optionally change `if ($stmt->fetch())` in favor of using `while($stmt->fetch())`

---

**Upload processor Suggestion**

Assuming you're using the code in your question ["Auto submit is not posting data to database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55576614/auto-submit-is-not-posting-data-to-database) for the file uploading, I highly recommend that you rewrite the upload processor using current standards/best-practices, which will also make your upload processor compatible with this answer.

Using `addslashes` or other escaping techniques can cause issues with the resulting `LOB` data stored in the database. Which I surmise is the cause for the complications you are experiencing now.

You should also take into consideration the max packet size that is used by your PHP and database environment, that limits the data size that can be sent or received by your application, which can lead to truncated `LOB` data. Because of the packet size limits, it is recommended that you use [`send_long_data`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php) to prevent issues with your application transmitting the `LOB` data.

*upload-form.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<form id="target" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmImage" class="frmImageUpload" action="./post.php">
   <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" class="userfile"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*post.php*

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','user','','db');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit;
}
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
//never trust data from GLOBALS
$user_id = filter_var($_SESSION['user_id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if (false === $user_id ||
    !isset($_FILES) ||
    !array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES) ||
    UPLOAD_ERR_OK !== $_FILES['userfile']['error'] ||
    $_FILES['userfile']['size'] <= 0 ||
    !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])
) {
    //invalid user or file upload
    exit;
}
//params = { 0: user_id, 1: content }
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO temp (user_id, content) VALUES (?, ?)');
if ($stmt) {
    //bind default value as NULL
    $null = null;
    $stmt->bind_param('ib', $user_id, $null);
    //max packet size limits can lead to partial file data being inserted
    $fp = new SplFileObject($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'rb', false);
    while (!$fp->eof()) {
        //use send_long_data to send the file data in chunks
        //be sure the first argument matches the param index for the LOB data column
        $stmt->send_long_data(1, $fp->fread(2048));
    }
    unset($fp);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
$conn->close();
```

---

As a personal recommendation; over the years I have come to discover that storing `LOB` data within the database has caused some serious issues. While it does increase the portability and ease of file management within applications. It has greatly hindered data recovery and backup, by significantly increasing the amount of I/O time needed to recover the database and hard drive RAID integrity. Also when used with other data, significantly increases query and maintenance times with the database. Forcing us to migrate from `SELECT *` to explicitly avoid the `LOB` column data or skip the tables for optimization or re-indexing. Lastly it also prevented client-side caching without creating specific RESTful URLs to serve the files. Overall it became much more trouble than was worth the effort to store the `LOB` data. I suggest using your web server to store the physical file(s), and use the database to store the relative path to the physical file, where PHP manages the absolute paths to the physical file(s) for viewing/manipulation. For example when creating thumbnails that can be cached and served from a publicly accessible location.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the browser PDF viewer, note you can only view one PDF at a time.

Your code would look like:

```
<?php
  header("Content-type:application/pdf");
  $tpurchase_id = $_GET['tpurchase_id'];
  $conn = new mysqli("localhost","user","","db");
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM temp_purchase WHERE tpurchase_id= '$tpurchase_id'";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
      ob_clean();
      flush();
      echo $row['content'];
      $conn->close();
      exit();
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: I see characters in my browser. The same characters as I see when I open the PDF file in Notepad.

Comment: @John That means your header is not set. Trying moving `header("Content-type:application/pdf");` to the top of the file

Comment: I dont get the characters anymore. The PDF opens in a full screen and shows a error message: "Error: Failed to load PDF document."

Comment: @John looks like you getting closer... Did you add `ob_clean(); flush();` before `echo $row['content'];`. Also check if the blob is type of PDF and remove any other headers you might have

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution: It gets the **encoded** LONGBLOB and **decodes** it, then displays it after setting a header. Its based on the answer from fyrye.

```
<?php
    $tpurchase_id = $_GET['tpurchase_id'];
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost","user","","db");
    $sql = "SELECT content FROM temp_purchase WHERE tpurchase_id = ?";

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bind_param("s", $tpurchase_id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($pdf_encoded);

    if($statement->fetch()){
        $pdf_decoded = base64_decode($pdf_encoded);
    }
    $statement->close();

    ob_start();
    ob_clean(); //Clear the buffer
    header('content-type: application/pdf');
    echo($pdf_decoded);
    ob_end_flush(); //Output only the buffered content to the client

?>
```

Comment: Generally you need to explicitly call `ob_start();` as [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) is disabled by default in PHP.

Comment: You're right. Does it matter if you put it at the top or just above `ob_clean();`?

Comment: The concept is to buffer everything from before the `ob_clean()` so that way ob_clean erases the buffer, and nothing is sent prior to it. Without calling `ob_start` on the first line, any warnings, echo, errors prior to `ob_start` will be sent to the client. You should also remove the closing PHP tag and use exit instead, as per my explanation in my answer.

Comment: When I write `exit` instead of closing tag `?>` it doesn't close out the PHP, and I have HTML after that point as well. Can you explain it?

Comment: why would you have HTML after sending a header content-type of `application/pdf`? As i explained in my answer, unless you're transitioning from PHP to another plain/text or markup language, you don't need the closing tag. `exit` prevents additional text from being parsed or sent to the client, such as a newline after the closing tag, which has a tendency to cause undesired behavior. If the script is expected to be included, simply leave out both the exit and closing tag, such as with database connection scripts. It's also less overhead on the lexer for needing to parse open/close tags